# How to change the Start Menu icon for a Windows Application?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

How do you change the icon for a Windows Application on the Start Menu? My specific target is Skype.

Comment: The icon image used by an application is normally compiled into the executable.  You can only change the icon image of the shortcut.  How you have change the icon of a shortcut has remained unchanged since Windows XP

Comment: It may be edited by changing the resource image in that exe file.

Comment: To do this you have to access the WindowsApps folder: [link](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-access-windowsapps-folder-in-windows-10/)